# Pegar a string de uma requisição inexistente

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Como pegar a string de uma requisição inexistente?

Estou usando .htaccess para redirecionar requisições de url's inexistentes (error 404).

Mas gostaria de quando a página 404.php fosse exibida, gostaria de pegar a url inexistente que o cliente digitou. Ou seja, a url inexistente!

Tem como?

$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] não funcionou! Retornou valor vazio!

página php

```
  <h1>Oh não! 404 Página Não Encontrada!</h1>
  <p>
    O que você tentou encontrar não está aqui.
  </p>

  <br /> <br />

  <h2>Detalhes:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>URI que você tentou: <?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; ?></li>
    <li>Data atual: <?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></li>
  </ul>

  <br /><br /><br />
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost/php/andre/provedor/index.php
    ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost/php/andre/provedor/401.php
    ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/php/andre/provedor403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/php/andre/provedor/404.php
    ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/php/andre/provedor/500.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tente $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Comment: Deu a própria página de erro! O que eu queria a página inexistente que o cliente tentou acessar!

Comment: Talvez tenha que tratar em algum arquivo PHP, pois creio que o .htaccess vai redirecionar sempre que encontrar o erro. Use um index.php e trate as navegações das páginas

Comment: sim. Mas imagine que o cliente tente ***site/paginaInexistente.php*** queria que a página 404.php pegasse essa url. Se a url fosse existente e o 404.php recebesse esse redirecionamento, o reuquest_uri pegava o valor da url

Comment: é..mas acho que na prática não funciona, pois quem está tratando isso é o .htaccess, e creio que não tenha a função de gravar essa página que o cliente tentou por ele.

Comment: isso não vai ser fácil pois não vai chegar a acessar página alguma!